# Determine date columns in a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv, date

I have simple `*.csv` file where some of the columns are dates of the format `mm/dd/yy`. Here is an example:

```
$ cat somefile.csv
05/09/15,8,Apple,05/09/15
06/10/15,5,Banana,06/10/12
05/11/18,4,Carrot,09/03/18
02/09/15,2,Apple,01/09/15
```

I want to easily determine if a column only contains valid dates,
but I find myself struggling with counting `'/'` and counting characters. Surely there is some simple way of doing it right?

**EDIT** (Answer from @RahulAgarwal)

Here's my script (which still doesn't work :(( )

```
###########
# IMPORTS #
###########
import csv
import sys
import numpy
from dateutil.parser import parse

###########################
# [1] Open input csv file #
###########################
myfile=open("input4.csv","r")
myreader = csv.reader(myfile)

############################
# [2] read header csv file #
############################
for myline in myreader:
    myheader=myline
    break

####################################################################
# [3] read and put in ds only data originating in specific columns #
####################################################################
for myline in myreader:
    for myColIndex in range(len(myline)):
        if (parse(myline[myColIndex])):
            print("column = {0}".format(myColIndex))

######################
# [4] Close csv file #
######################
myfile.close()
```

Comment: Do you want to check if a value is a valid date or not?

Comment: @MayankPorwal yes.

Comment: You want to check its a valid date or to determine whether the column contains date or string or int etc.

Comment: I want to be able to find columns where every entry in the column is a valid date

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far and explain in detail what's not working. Best done by describing the expected and the actual behaviour. If your code throws an exception please include the full error trace.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: If  my answer or any of the below answer solved your problem, do accept for future users!!

Comment: What version of Python are you using that you're importing from `sets`? What is the exact output you're after here... Is it something like: "Column 1 and 3 contain valid dates for all rows" ?

Comment: @JonClements yes, something like column 2 and 4 contain only valid dates

Comment: @OrenIshShalom and what Python version... that `from sets import Set` is very odd :)

Comment: python version 2.7.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set to keep track of columns seen in the file and a set of columns that didn't parse successfully as a valid date, then the difference between those two is columns that did parse as date, eg:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('yourfile.csv') as fin:
    seen_columns = set()
    invalid_columns = set()
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        for colno, col in enumerate(row, 1):
            # We've seen it contains a non-date - don't try and parse it again
            if colno in invalid_columns:
                continue

            # Make a note we've seen column N
            seen_columns.add(colno)

            # Try and see if we can parse it to the desired date format
            try:
                datetime.strptime(col, '%m/%d/%y')
            # Nope - we couldn't... not a date - so don't both checking again
            except ValueError:
                invalid_columns.add(colno)

    # Columns containing dates are those we've seen that
    # didn't fail to parse as a date...
    valid_columns = seen_columns - invalid_columns
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below to check for valid dates:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse("05/09/15")
```

Comment: I can't seem to make it work when I use `if (parse(myline[myColIndex])):` because it always returns true, even if it's not a date ... Could you please add a minimal nested loop that scans the `*.csv` file and asks whether it's a date or not? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the strptime method of the datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime
def isDateValid(date, pattern = "%d/%m/%y"):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(date, pattern)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

The *strptime* method raises a *ValueError* if the string doesn't match the *pattern*.

**EDIT:**

to let this work:

```
from datetime import datetime
def isDateValid(date, pattern = "%d/%m/%y"):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(date, pattern)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

# load file
with open("filename.csv") as f:
    # split file into lines
    lines = f.readlines()

    # replace new-line character
    lines = [x.replace("\n", "") for x in lines]

    # extract the header
    header = lines[0]

    # extract rows
    rows = lines[1:]

    # loop over every row
    for rowNumber, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        # split row into the seperate columns
        columns = line.split(",")

        # setting default value for every row
        gotValidDate = False

        # loop over every column
        for column in columns:
            # check if the column got a valid date
            if isDateValid(column):
                gotValidDate = True

        # if at least one out of all columns in that row got a valid date
        # the row number gets printed
        if gotValidDate:
            print(f"Row {rowNumber} got at least one valid date")
```

(Code is written in Python 3.7)